# I am Migrating the data from one server to other server with SSIS Package and Triggered that package in Azure Data Factory(ADF)

Tags: ssis, azure-data-factory

I am Migrating the data from one server (azuredatabase) server to other server with SSIS Package. I am trigerring this in Azure Data Factory (ADF). But for 1 table data has arrount 1.3 million data. So, to complete that load it is taking arround 130 min of time in Azure. Is there any solution to complete the load faster.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/nHIyw.png)

I am Migrating the data from one server (azuredatabase) server to other server with SSIS Package. I am trigerring this in Azure Data Factory (ADF). But for 1 table data has arrount 1.3 million data. So, to complete that load it is taking arround 130 min of time in Azure. Is there any solution to complete the load faster.

Answer (score 0):

> According to **shubs** mentioned in [The DefaultBufferMaxRows and DefaultBufferSize Properties in SSIS](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/the-defaultbuffermaxrows-and-defaultbuffersize-properties-in-ssis), it says:
>
> > for large data volumes the default values would not necessarily give you the best performance and hence a certain level of manipulation is required for improving the data flow performance.

`DefaultBufferMaxRows` and `DefaultBufferSize` are two of the Data Flow Task settings that might be utilized to improve data extractions.

**DefaultBufferMaxRows:** The number of rows that may be kept in these buffers is indicated by this parameter.

**DefaultBufferSize:** The default buffer size for storing rows momentarily is indicated by this parameter (in bytes).

also, there is property called [AutoAdjustBufferSize](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141031.aspx) which, if set to "true," disregards the `DefaultBufferSize` option and determines the actual buffer size using the `DefaultBufferMaxRows`.

Reference: [Data Flow Performance Features](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/data-flow-performance-features?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver16)